# Add icons to JButton using custom font from AwesomeFont and unicode characters in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, fonts, jbutton, font-awesome

I have a JButton and I want to add an icon to it. I would like to use the font based icons from FontAwesome which provides a TrueType font file. The icon I am trying to add is the play button icon. The play button icon in the css file for FontAwesome is `\f04b` which I beleive translates to `\uf04b` in Java.

This is how I am loading the font in the constructor of by IconButton base class.

```
public class IconButton extends JButton {
  public IconButton() {
    try {
      InputStream in = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/fontawesome-webfont.ttf");
      Font ttfBase = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, in);
      Font ttfReal = ttfBase.deriveFont(Font.BOLD, 24);
      setFont(ttfReal);
    } catch (FontFormatException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

In the implementing class StartButton this is how I am setting the text.

```
public class StartButton extends IconButton {
  public StartButton() {
    setText(String.valueOf('\u0f4b'));
    setForeground(Color.BLACK);
  }
}
```

This is what I get. Nothing.

[image: JButton]

Any help is much appreciated.

EDIT: See answer below.

Comment: That first code wold not compile (`createFont` throws exceptions that are neither caught nor declared), and it seems terrible design of the two classes shown ( 1. the first class could create the Font once and cache it as a static attribute 2. if it defined a constructor based around a String for the text, calling the super constructor, it could avoid the second class completely).  Alternately A. since `IconButton` sets a `Font` and `StartButton` sets a foreground color, use a standard `JButton` and hand each one to a method to configure the look. B. Use a new PLAF or adjust the `UIManager`

Comment: The code wasn't pulled verbatim from the application in order to reduce noise, but for completeness sake I've updated it to include the try/catch. I would also add that I agree it should only create the Font once. Good suggestion.

I'll have to look into PLAF and the UIManger.

Comment: *"The code wasn't pulled verbatim from the application"*  Probably better to describe it in words or pseudo-code (clearly marked as such) rather than Java code in that case.  Good call on updating it.  :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think I solved this actually. The correct character is `\uf04b` not `\u0f4b`. Whoops! :)

This is working for me now.

[image: JButton with Play Icon]

Answer (score 2):

Try jIconFont (Swing or JavaFX) at http://jiconfont.github.io/

Example:

```
Icon icon = IconFontSwing.buildIcon(FontAwesome.FLOPPY_O, 15);

JButton button = new JButton(icon);
```

Comment: Please don't copy and paste the exact same answer to multiple questions

Comment: My apologies. How should I proceed when the answer to multiple questions is exactly the same?