# Font Awsome on JButton

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to display **[font awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/)** icons on a `JButton`. I did the following

```
Font font = null;
try
{
    font = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("../icons/fontawesome-webfont.ttf"));
    font = font.deriveFont(18f);

    GraphicsEnvironment ge = 
        GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    ge.registerFont(font);
}
catch ( FontFormatException ex ){ex.printStackTrace();}
catch ( IOException ex ){ex.printStackTrace();}

private JButton save_btn = new JButton();
save_btn.setFont(font);
save_btn.setText("\uf0c7");
save_btn.setPreferredSize( buttonDimension );
```

But everything I get is [image]

If I use the font **with a JTextArea, it works fine** :

```
JTextArea t = new JTextArea();
t.setRows( 2);
t.setColumns( 12);
t.setFont( font );
t.setText( "\uF0F3 \uF1EC \uf0f3 \uf1ec");
buttonPanel.add(t);
```

I get [image]

Comment: What's the output for `System.out.println(font.canDisplay("\uf0c7"));`?

Comment: Check weather is font supported into the system our not?

Comment: Did you reference the correct character code? Here's a similar problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9639894/add-icons-to-jbutton-using-custom-font-from-awesomefont-and-unicode-characters-i

Comment: ge.registerFont(font);  returns a boolean. What is its value?

Comment: font.canDisplay && registerFont both return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that your button dimensions are too small for displaying the symbol you want to display and the button reverts to showing "..." which don't seem to have good representations in font-awesome.

Comment: Yes I think your guess is good but is there a way to force the text to be displayed anyway ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5808195/removing-the-three-dots-from-a-jbutton

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, I removed

```
save_btn.setPreferredSize( buttonDimension );
```

And now it works fine !

[image]

Comment: You could also set the margin insets to 0. That way the margins to the left and right will come in (if that's what you were attempting to do with the `setPreferredSize`... `button.setMargins(new Insets(0, 0, 0, 0));`